# What does it mean, "coked-out MOR shit"?

Tags: plot-explanation, rocketman-2019

In *Rocketman* (2019), songwriter Elton says to Reid:

> Elton: Why don't you sell my fucking records? Number 11 in Italy.
>
> Reid: The song doesn't work, that's the problem. The record's
> **coked-out MOR shit**.

What does it mean, "coked-out MOR shit"?

Comment: "Coked-out" presumably refers to cocaine usage (i.e. "this sounds like it was made while you were on drugs"), but I have no idea what MOR is supposed to stand for in this context.

Comment: @F1Krazy MOR = Middle of the Road

Comment: Once again, I would encourage you to use English Language Learners.SE for questions regarding explanations of English euphenisms

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an English language comprehension question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @F1Krazy states, “coked out” refers to it sounding like he was high when it was written. MOR means “middle of the road”. It is a genre of music in itself but, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_of_the_road_(music)) states, it is also used as a derogatory term, usually meaning overly commercial, bland or banal music. I.E. unexciting.